# How to copy all chars(include '\0') from one array to another without using strcpy function?

Tags: c, arrays, char, copy

copy all characters from one character array to another without using strcpy function.

```
char s1[80],s2[80];
int i;
printf("input s2");
scanf("%s",&s2);
for(i=0;i<=strlen(s2);i++)
    s1[i]=s2[i];
printf("s1:%s",s1);
```

Comment: Doesn't it already work ?

Comment: Like this: `for (i = 0; s1[i] = s2[i]; i++);` Now for the homework assignment: figure out why the heck does this even work ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that's a neat way !

Comment: What is your question? Please keep the title a short summary of the problem you have, and ask an actual question inside the question body. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of scanf, using gets function for getting input with spaces.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char s1[80],s2[80];
int i;
printf("input s2");
// scanf("%c",&s2);
gets(s2);
printf("%d",strlen(s2));
for(i=0;i<strlen(s2);i++)
    {
        s1[i]=s2[i];

    }

printf("s1:%s",s1);

}
```